# Multi Sig Sub Keys

Tags: multi-signature, bip32-hd-wallets

When talking about HD (BIP-32?) wallets, I hear talk of Multi Sig and Key Derivation / Chains. Is it possible to mix these two concepts?

e.g. I want to store the majority of my coins with a 2 of 3 multi sig wallet, but would like to store a small subset of coins in a child key derived from the 2 of 3 wallet such that if I the child key was compromised, I could use the parent 2 of 3 wallet to spend those funds.

Is this possible or am I speaking gibberish?

Comment: I think Copay does this.

Comment: I donwloaded Copay on my Android device because I heard rumors as well, but could not figure out how.

Comment: configure it in multisig mode with several linked wallets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's called HDM (Hierarchical-Deterministic-Multisig).

There's no standard, per se, and the main proponent (to the best of my knowledge) is/has been Vitalik Buterin, of Ethereum/Bitcoin Magazine fame.

There's code in the Python *[pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools)* library which allows one to implement this on a low level. The functions are called:

1. `bip32_hdm_script` and
2. `bip32_hdm_addr`

The format is: `bip32_hdm_script([xprv1, xprv2, xprv3...], (0, 1..))`, where the xprvs are as a list, and the integers proceeding it represent path derivation (**NOTE: the ints must be a tuple**). So, `0,1` means `k/0/1`. Use `1+2**31` for `1H`. **This function returns the multi-sig redeem script**, so you'll pipe it into `bip32_hdm_addr` (which simply returns the p2sh addresses)

Of course you'll also use the script to sign transactions. There's a [useful fork of pybitcointools available](https://github.com/simcity4242/pybitcointools) with added functionality and regular updates, which could be more useful in this endeavor (vs the sporadically updated source library).

---

A similar question - ***Clarification of BIP32 hierarchical deterministic multisig scripts*** - was recently [asked](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36919/9382) and [answered](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/37087/9382) by me too

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer... It looks like I have some reading to do. Do you know if there is a wallet that implements this functionality?

Comment: Possibly Electrum 2.0

Comment: @zanegray In addition to Electrum 2.x (which I can confirm supports HDM), there's also mSIGNA and Armory (although Armory is not hierarchical/BIP-32 yet). The latter two both require a Bitcoin Core node, for better or worse. There are plenty of online multisig wallets which use BIP-32/39 concepts to achieve 2fa, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're looking for....

Comment: @zanegray Check out the edit referencing a similar question